# How to put a variable into a string - C

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm trying to make a program that take a n and then does n! and shows the formula for it I.E 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24. However, I can't figure out how to insert variables into my string at specified intervals.

This is a typically response with what I have now:

```
Enter an interger between 0 (not including 0) and 9 (-1 to quit): 4
♦*♥*☻*☺=╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠↑
```

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SENTINEL -1

void fact_calc(int x)
{
    int ans = 1;
    char string[50];
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        ans *= x;
        string[i] = ("%d", x);
        i++;
        if (x != 1)
        {
            string[i] = ('*');
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            string[i] = ('=');
            i++;
        }
        x--;
    } while (x != 0);

    printf("%s \n", string);
    string[i] = ("%d", ans);
}


void main(void)
{
    int x;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter an interger between 0 (not including 0) and 9 (-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if ((x > 0) && (x <= 9))
        {
            fact_calc(x);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter a valid input \n");
        }
    } while (x != -1);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, terminating null-character is required for C string. Secondly, a *comma operator* is used in `("%d", x)` and this is equivalent to simple `x`. You may want `x + '0'` instead.

Comment: If all you're doing with the string is printing it at the end, why even put it in a string? Just print it where you're currently trying to put it in the string.

Comment: `char string[50];` --> `char string[50] = { 0 };`

Comment: `string[i] = ("%d", x);` -> `string[i] = '0' + x;` (But that will only work for x < 10)

Comment: `string[i] = ("%d", ans);` just delete

Comment: You're doing `string[i] = ("%d", x); i++;` which [although valid C, it produces warnings when compiled with `-Wall`] isn't what you want. I think you want `sprintf` and the following: `i += sprintf(&string[i],"%d",x);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Strings in C is terminated by a null-character `'\0'`. You have to add that or specify the length to print.
- The comma in `string[i] = ("%d", x);` and `string[i] = ("%d", ans);` are *comma operator*. It is evaluated to the value of second operand, which is `x` and `ans` in this case. In this case what you want should be `x + '0'`. Character code for numbers are defined to be continuous in C specification, so you can convert one-digit integer to character in this way.

Try this:

```
void fact_calc(int x)
{
    int ans = 1;
    char string[50];
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        ans *= x;
        /* string[i] = ("%d", x); */
        string[i] = x + '0'; /* use correct way to convert an integer to a character */
        i++;
        if (x != 1)
        {
            string[i] = ('*');
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            string[i] = ('=');
            i++;
        }
        x--;
    } while (x != 0);

    string[i] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    printf("%s \n", string);
    /* this is meaningless because string is not used later */
    /* string[i] = ("%d", ans); */
}
```

Instead of this part

```
    string[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s \n", string);
```

You can specify the length to print like this:

```
    printf("%.*s \n", i, string);
```

Comment: I'm not sure `string[i] = x + '0';` is enough if `x >= 10`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is either but it doesn't get to that point because my parameters are between 0-9 but this did work for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a soution that will work for values of x greater than 9, you can replace your `string[i] = ("%d", x);` with `i += sprintf(&string[i],"%d",x);` By your use of `"%d"`, I assume this is what you meant, but `%d` is only recognized by the `scanf` family of functions (on input) and the `printf` family of functions (on output). In particular, `sprintf` performs a formatted print to a string. The entire family of `printf` functions return the number of characters printed, which is why I use that to update the value of `i`. You will, of course, also need to replace `string[i] = ("%d", ans);` with `sprintf(&string[i],"%d",ans);`... which should appear *before* your printf, not after. Note that the `i +=` is not needed here, because `i` is not used again. Also note that this last `sprintf` puts your terminating null in place, so it is not necessary to put it in explicitly.

But be careful, because for `x` values much larger than 9, your string size of 50 will not be sufficient.